# Android Apps: How can I view an apps code/files?

Tags: android, mobile, app

I love taking apart applications, software, and websites to see how developers were able to create a feature or how a game handles AI.

Something I'd like to be able to do is view an app's files (code specifically) but I haven't been able to find a solution on Google. I've seen YouTube videos before mention things about looking through an apps files but was unable to find those videos again to contact the creator.

What I've tried is:

`apps>> My Files >> Device Storage >> Android >> Data >> com.Company.AppName`

From here I've only seen a "cache" folder which I don't think is what I'm looking for and is empty anyway.

I've also tried looking at `settings >> applications >> Applications manager >> [tap on app name]`

From here I have the option of adding the add to my SD card.

I also have an iPad in case it's easier (which I highly doubt) to do this on an Apple device.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the source code of applications a few ways.

1. Check if the application is open source
2. Contact the developer and request source code
3. Reverse engineer the application

Reverse engineering is a bit of a legal grey area. From [www.eff.org](https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq)

> **First the Scary Stuff: What Kinds of Reverse Engineering Are Most**
>   **Legally Risky? ^**
>
> By using the term "legally risky" here, we aren't saying that the
>   activity is certainly legal or illegal. We're saying that these are
>   areas where the law may apply so any researcher considering these
>   steps should take the time to think it through and probably get some
>   legal help.
>
> - If your access to the code or computer system you are studying is
>     conditioned upon agreeing to any contractual terms (e.g. End User
>     License Agreements (EULA), terms of service notices (TOS), terms of
>     use notices (TOU), a non-disclosure agreement (NDA), developers
>     agreement or API agreement), you are at greater legal risk if your
>     research activities do not comply with their stated terms and
>     conditions. You should talk to a lawyer before agreeing to any terms
>     and before studying any software distributed with such terms and
>     conditions, even if you have come into possession of that code without
>     agreeing to anything.
> - It is extremely risky to disclose or use any information you obtained
>     subject to an NDA or other negotiated contractual obligation of
>     confidentiality.
> - It is legally risky to study software you do not possess legally.
> - It is legally risky to make any copies of software that have not been
>     authorized by the copyright owner (such as by a license agreement).
> - It is legally risky to bypass any “technical protection measures”
>     (e.g., authentication handshakes, protocol encryption, password
>     authentication, code obfuscation, code signing) that control access to
>     the code or any specific functionality.
> - It is highly risky to copy any code into a program you create as a
>     result of reverse engineering, because that copy could infringe
>     copyright unless it is a fair use under copyright law. Note that
>     copying can include both imitation of non-functional elements as well
>     as verbatim duplication.
> - It is legally risky to perform any network packet inspection unless
>     (1) the network is configured to be accessible to the general public;
>     (2) you have consent of all users whose packets are intercepted; or
>     (3) you have consent of the network provider where the inspection is
>     necessary for provision of the service or to protect the network
>     provider’s rights and property.